# Can I search for a string of text inside Notes.app on an iPhone 5c (iOS 7.1)?

Tags: mac, ios, search, notes.app, iphone

I use Mac's Notes app on my MacBook Air (Mavericks).  I can readily search for any specific note just using <kbd>command</kbd> - <kbd>F</kbd>.

It finds notes containing the string of text either in the title of the note or in the body of the note.

However, when I sync all my notes to my iPhone 5c, I can't find how to search for a particular note in this way.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Drag down on the home screen (just touch in the middle of the icons and drag down) and the iPhone search box will appear. Searching there will reveal text in notes (in addition to other stuff like song titles)

Comment: This can be enabled/disabled on a per (built-in) app basis in ***Settings.app > General> Spotlight Search***.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with locked notes inside Notes.app. There is a search feature inside Notes.app too (pull down) but even that feature won't find text inside locked notes. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No!"  And it's a serious flaw.  The best you can do is find out which note has what you are looking for, but after that, you're on your own.

It seems like that should be something Apple could fix in an ios update but so far they haven't done it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a search feature inside Notes.app too (open a folder, then pull down to reveal the search bar).

And as @dwightk mentions the Spotlight search (pull down on home screen) can be used for searching too.

Unfortunately neither of the search methods won't find text inside locked notes.

> Notes that are locked don’t appear in the search results. To search
>   locked notes, select one, then enter your password to open them all.

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12084?locale=en_US